# C# routes using one controller

Tags: c#, routes

I'm new to C# and .net and I have question about routing.

I have a database table called `cms_page`. This table contains a column `page_url`.

I have a C# controller called `CmsPageController`. I want to use this controller to handle the page requests. Below are some examples of URLS that can be entered and these are stored in the `page_url` column of my `cms_page` table:

- `/com/en/aboutus`
- `/com/en/contactus`
- `/promotions/promo1`

So, when one of the above URL's is entered, the `CMSPageController` should run, and match the URL entered with the URL in the `cms_page` table and should return the `page_data` column in the `cms_page` table (which is the HTML to be displayed).

Can someone explain to me how this would be set up.

Comment: Please let me know for any page request, do you want to validate and put page data from database or for specific set of pages, you want data from database ??

Comment: Are you working with MVC?

Comment: I wonder if this is possible at all. In case, if you happen to work with `MVC`, does not `routes.config` work out for you?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?  It's all in there.  Start here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started, and come back if you still have questions.

Comment: I guess the only validation is to make sure the URL entered, exists in the cms_page table. If the URL doesn't exist, go to 404 page, otherwise display the page data.

Comment: Yes, I'm working with MVC

Comment: I've read the documentation, but I can't see anything that fits my requirement. I know all I need to do is set up routes.config, but I'm not sure what it should look like.

Comment: Routes.config is a file which defines how exactly the routing engine should respond to when a request is received. But, i doubt if there is a possibility in `MVC Routes.Config` to communicate with database at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to add a "catch all" route.

Here is an example of how to do that:

**Route Config**

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "PagesRoute",
     "{*pagepath}",
     new { Controller = "Pages", action = "Index" });
```

**Controller**

```
public class PagesController : Controller
{
    public string Index(string pagepath)
    {
        // TODO: PUT THE CODE IN HERE TO QUERY THE DATABASE AND RETURN THE OUTPUT
    }
}
```

**Important Note:** This route must be last!!  You must also set "ignore" routes for things like images and stylesheets.  Alternatively, you could make the route start with `page` so all pages will be at `/page/...`.  It doesn't look as nice, but it might be easier to manage in the long run.  Instead, you could also choose to end all pages with `.html` (or any other extension of your choice) and add a Regular Expression "Constraint" to match only URLs that end with `.html`.  (You can then strip off the extension before you do the database query.)

---

Among many good resources, both in the official documentation and outside of it, all about ASP.NET routing, one of the most useful is this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299531/Custom-routes-for-MVC-Application) about Custom Routes.  It describes all of this, plus lots more that you can do with the router.